# git: Rename root folder in large collaborative project without causing conflicts

Tags: python, git, rename, pull-request

I'm working on a git repo with maybe 50 other people, and for some reason we need to rename one of the root packages.

At any given moment there're maybe 20 active pull requests on this repo.  For what it's worth the codebase is mainly Python.  Since python uses absolute imports, that means that the import lines must change in any file that imports from other files in the package.

What is the best way to do the rename without causing a big headache (e.g. a bunch of merge conflicts) for either myself or the people trying to merge their pull requests?

Comment: From renaming and headache you can choose 0 or 2, not 1.

Comment: Not sure what's included on the package. From experience, git is quite intelligent when you use git mv to rename folders. You could get conflicts if at the same time you're doing this and before you do your commit and push, other people delete files on the folders you're moving. If they just modify, after they pull it'll be fast forwarded with no issues. Try to notify everyone that the change is coming so they don't let much time pass before they pull, though.

Comment: @Luc one issue is that renaming causes imports in every file to change, so not only are files moved but their import list is also modified.

Comment: You can do the git mv and change the imports in the same commit. It'll take no issue as long as other people don't modify the lines with the imports at the same time.